# InsertLastID from another table, into new table? Using PDO Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, prepared-statement

I have these two tables comments_tbl and news_comments_tbl, and i'm working with MySQL.

When i'm creating a comment i want to send the last created comments ID into a new table news_comments_tbl.

I was using this method before using prepared statements, and it worked fine:

```
//comment
$name     = $_POST['name'];
$comment  = $_POST['comment'];

//ID
$commentidfk  = $_POST['comments_id'];
$newsidfk     = $_POST['news_id_fk'];
$newsidfk     = $_GET['news_id_fk'];

if (isset($_POST['comment']))
{

  $sqlquery ="INSERT INTO comments_tbl(comments_id, name, comment)
  VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$comment')";
  $result = $conn->query($sqlquery) or die('Error');

  $sqlquery2 ="INSERT INTO news_comments_tbl(news_id_fk, comments_id_fk)
  VALUES ('$newsidfk', LAST_INSERT_ID())";
  $result2 = $conn->query($sqlquery2) or die('Error'); 

  header("location:news.php");

}
    else
    {
        echo 'Error';
    }
```

But now when i'm converting to using PDO prepared statement, i can't get it working. The comment is created, but i can't get the last inserted id inserted into the new table (news_comments_tbl)

This is how i'm doing it:

```
$query  = "INSERT INTO comments_tbl(comments_id, name, comment) VALUES (NULL,?,?)";

  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam(1,$name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(2,$comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $stmt->execute();

  return $conn->lastInsertId('comments_id');

  $query  = "INSERT INTO news_comments_tbl(news_id_fk, comments_id_fk) VALUES (?, LAST_INSERT_ID)";

  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam(1, $newsidfk, PDO::PARAM_INT);

  $stmt->execute();

  header("location:news.php");
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be issuing a return before executing the second prepared statement. And as previously stated, you are not calling `LAST_INSERT_ID` correctly in your second query, but you don't need it anyway. You're code should look more like this:

```
$comments_id = $conn->lastInsertId();

$query  = "INSERT INTO news_comments_tbl(news_id_fk, comments_id_fk) VALUES (?, ?)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $newsidfk, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $comments_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, and good luck with the rest of the project! If my answer helped please feel free to accept it when able. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just forgot braces for `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

To be notified of such errors, init your PDO with this command after connect:

```
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Comment: Nothing happens when i'm using 'LAST_INSERT_ID'?

Comment: Not sure where to write $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );, also nothing happens no matter where i put it.